# What does "Create a domain model via POCO classes" means?

Tags: c#, oop, poco, domain-model

I have an assessment to solve. In the project solution which is given to me, there is a **.csv** file expected from me to process it. Here is how it looks like;

```
asset id,file_name,mime_type,created_by,email,country,description
51df6a98-614e-40ef-8885-95ae50940058,ElitProin.aam,application/x-authorware-map,sblack0,jmitchell0@huffingtonpost.com,United States,Maecenas ut massa quis augue luctus tincidunt. Nulla mollis molestie lorem. Quisque ut erat.
279899c1-bc63-495c-94c5-57f25c881ed2,MusVivamusVestibulum.xla,application/x-excel,iadams1,rhenry1@xrea.com,Canada,"Curabitur in libero ut massa volutpat convallis. Morbi odio odio, elementum eu, interdum eu, tincidunt in, leo. Maecenas pulvinar lobortis est."
3060b1db-9a0a-4046-b10a-b90a0c440070,NullaUltrices.sit,application/x-sit,jmatthews2,jadams2@ft.com,Japan,"Duis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue elementum."
7ef8ddf4-0b60-43e6-9e17-21029da02c69,Eros.tsv,text/tab-separated-values,dadams3,jmoreno3@joomla.org,Serbia,"Curabitur in libero ut massa volutpat convallis. Morbi odio odio, elementum eu, interdum eu, tincidunt in, leo. Maecenas pulvinar lobortis est."
588610a3-b546-4c2e-822d-c822ba20a775,BlanditNam.aim,application/x-aim,dpierce4,aortiz4@devhub.com,United States,In congue. Etiam justo. Etiam pretium iaculis justo.
3de294a8-8f13-4f86-b447-92e8fd79277d,NecCondimentumNeque.jpe,image/jpeg,pyoung5,ckim5@ft.com,Romania,"Fusce posuere felis sed lacus. Morbi sem mauris, laoreet ut, rhoncus aliquet, pulvinar sed, nisl. Nunc rhoncus dui vel sem."
209bf3d7-e792-4f3f-98e8-240efcf81e31,DuisMattisEgestas.gif,image/gif,ldaniels6,mreid6@seattletimes.com,Belgium,"Curabitur in libero ut massa volutpat convallis. Morbi odio odio, elementum eu, interdum eu, tincidunt in, leo. Maecenas pulvinar lobortis est."
975eaf96-dd9f-4534-89a6-0ebabb730aa0,HacHabitassePlatea.arj,application/octet-stream,smorales7,jgarrett7@geocities.jp,Spain,In congue. Etiam justo. Etiam pretium iaculis justo.
```

The applications which is asked from me to complete is like this;

```
// Create a domain model via POCO classes to store the data available in the CSV file below
// Objects to be present in the domain model: Asset, Country and Mime type
// Process the file in the most robust way possible
// The use of 3rd party plugins is permitted
```

So from what I understood from these steps, I have implemented a class structure;

```
    public class Asset
    {
        public int assetID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public int countryName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mime
    {
        public int mime { get; set; }
    }
```

But about the lack of theoretical concept behind POCO, I am not sure what I am doing, or what should I do.

1. Is that a correct "domain model" what I implemented?
2. Where I should use the other headers such as "file_name", "email"
   which is stated in .csv file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: POCO just stands for *Plain Old CLR Objects*. they are just regular classes

Comment: Anyway, there is a lot of information missing in this question, and this is something you should really ask your teacher, or investigate your notes from what you have learned. I assume the idea is read the CSV file and create a sort of normalized class structure to hold this data. Though from the information you have given its hard to tell

Comment: I can tell you that none of those fields are `int`s, and I think the expectation is for one class to have all the properties, not one class per property though I can see how you got that from the wording of the requirement.

Comment: I have the same assignment to resolve and am confused about it! did you get the chance to the bottom of it?

Comment: seems like all have applied for the sitecore position opening.