# Splitting a string which consist of a CSV file

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, split

I have a CSV file which consists of such data;

```
asset id,file_name,mime_type,created_by,email,country,description
51df6a98-614e-40ef-8885-95ae50940058,ElitProin.aam,application/x-authorware-map,sblack0,jmitchell0@huffingtonpost.com,United States,Maecenas ut massa quis augue luctus tincidunt. Nulla mollis molestie lorem. Quisque ut erat.
279899c1-bc63-495c-94c5-57f25c881ed2,MusVivamusVestibulum.xla,application/x-excel,iadams1,rhenry1@xrea.com,Canada,"Curabitur in libero ut massa volutpat convallis. Morbi odio odio, elementum eu, interdum eu, tincidunt in, leo. Maecenas pulvinar lobortis est."
3060b1db-9a0a-4046-b10a-b90a0c440070,NullaUltrices.sit,application/x-sit,jmatthews2,jadams2@ft.com,Japan,"Duis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue elementum."
7ef8ddf4-0b60-43e6-9e17-21029da02c69,Eros.tsv,text/tab-separated-values,dadams3,jmoreno3@joomla.org,Serbia,"Curabitur in libero ut massa volutpat convallis. Morbi odio odio, elementum eu, interdum eu, tincidunt in, leo. Maecenas pulvinar lobortis est."
588610a3-b546-4c2e-822d-c822ba20a775,BlanditNam.aim,application/x-aim,dpierce4,aortiz4@devhub.com,United States,In congue. Etiam justo. Etiam pretium iaculis justo.
3de294a8-8f13-4f86-b447-92e8fd79277d,NecCondimentumNeque.jpe,image/jpeg,pyoung5,ckim5@ft.com,Romania,"Fusce posuere felis sed lacus. Morbi sem mauris, laoreet ut, rhoncus aliquet, pulvinar sed, nisl. Nunc rhoncus dui vel sem."
209bf3d7-e792-4f3f-98e8-240efcf81e31,DuisMattisEgestas.gif,image/gif,ldaniels6,mreid6@seattletimes.com,Belgium,"Curabitur in libero ut massa volutpat convallis. Morbi odio odio, elementum eu, interdum eu, tincidunt in, leo. Maecenas pulvinar lobortis est."
975eaf96-dd9f-4534-89a6-0ebabb730aa0,HacHabitassePlatea.arj,application/octet-stream,smorales7,jgarrett7@geocities.jp,Spain,In congue. Etiam justo. Etiam pretium iaculis justo.
5a8393df-d4aa-4734-8df4-10a611cd5cc7,NullaSuscipit.rt,text/vnd.rn-realtext,jschmidt8,rbowman8@prnewswire.com,United States,"Duis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue elementum."
f41dd5e6-8833-4b22-8e33-edcb024c4c1f,Odio.mime,message/rfc822,cholmes9,rjones9@accuweather.com,Nigeria,"Fusce posuere felis sed lacus. Morbi sem mauris, laoreet ut, rhoncus aliquet, pulvinar sed, nisl. Nunc rhoncus dui vel sem."
74d04563-f253-4fcb-8caa-dfb2e1bba7ed,SuspendissePotentiCras.list,text/plain,tlawsona,sstevensa@ft.com,United States,"Proin eu mi. Nulla ac enim. In tempor, turpis nec euismod scelerisque, quam turpis adipiscing lorem, vitae mattis nibh ligula nec sem."
```

I have loaded it into a string variable, so I can access it as a whole string. But I want to split this whole string into pieces to access it with its .csv logic. I am using "," as the delimiter;

```
string[] values = s.Split(',');
```

The problem here is that, in the .csv file which I am working with, there is a **"description"** header, and under this header, there are texts which contains commas.

```
"Curabitur in libero ut massa volutpat convallis. Morbi odio odio, elementum eu, interdum eu, tincidunt in, leo. Maecenas pulvinar lobortis est."
```

However, these commas should not be separating the whole "csv string", the only delimiter of this file must be the commas which separate different header's values. Because I am handling this csv file inside one, whole string, the `Split()` method is applying splitting operation on these commas which are located in text values as well.

How can I handle this issue so that I am going to get a split array which imitates the logic of a csv file? Any help is appreciated, thanks..

Comment: You handle this by not trying to parse a csv file with `string.Split` use a dedicated csv parser

Comment: I can't use, this is an assesment and any third party software, plugin or package is forbidden to use.

Comment: From you last question it seems you need to reread the requirements, quote *"The use of 3rd party plugins is permitted"* expressly denoted  in your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094966/what-does-create-a-domain-model-via-poco-classes-means

Comment: An option (just for this task, otherwise get [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)) is to check whether the splitted strings count is `> 6` and if it is, rebuild the strings from index 5 on (using `string.Join(", ", [Sub array])`).

Comment: Can you delimit your CSV with pipes **|** ? It'll be much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RegExp for parsing the csv:
here is an example:

```
Regex CSVParser = new Regex("^(?:([^",]+))?(?=,)|(?<=,)(?:[^",]*)?(?=[,$])|((?<=")[^"(\s*,)][^"]*(?="))|(?<=")(?=")|(?<=,)(?:[^,"])*(?=$)");
String[] Fields = CSVParser.Split(s);
```

you can find more regexp examples by searching ""C# regex for reading csv file" or something like this.